# How to run a Wordpress-CMS and an Angular 9 distribution in one domain?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, wordpress

I'm trying to install my Angular universal app and my CMS in a single domain. Therefore I would like to put the CMS (which is Wordpress) in a subdirectory.
My current directory structure looks like this:

```
/httpdocs
|---dist        ...contains the Angular app
|---rest        ...contains backend REST-API files written in PHP
|---cms         ...contains the CMS Wordpress installation
```

My `ngxinx` configuration is:

```
location ~ /rest {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ^~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

And my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rest/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rest/index.php#  [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteBase /cms/

RewriteRule ^wp-(.*)$ /cms/wp-$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^packages/(.*)$ /cms/packages/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^\?page_id=(.*)$ /cms/index.php?page_id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /cms/news/(.*)$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
https://MYURL.com/                  -> opens my Angular app
https://MYURL.com/rest/xxx          -> calls the REST-API of my Angular app
https://MYURL.com/wp-admin          -> opens my CMS Admin
https://MYURL.com/wp-json/wp/v2/... -> calls the CMS REST-API
```

But whatever I try, wheather the Angular app is running or the CMS, but not both. Does anybody see where I do the error? Is there also maybe a possibility to do all in ngnix. Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: Are you going to use WordPress only for serving the WP REST API?

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes and no. Wordpress is used to serve the data via the REST-API. But I also need to login to the backend panel, to write and to preview articles. So I guess that the complete functionality is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are quite unusual. You can try this one:

```
server {
    ...
    root /path/to/httpdocs;

    # serve any request starting with `/rest` with the following location
    location ^~ /rest {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    # assuming every request starting with '/wp-' and every other request for PHP file
    # (except those starting with '/rest') are WordPress related
    location ~ (^/wp-|\.php$) {
        root /path/to/httpdocs/cms;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    # serve all the other requests with the Angular app
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Edited version based on Ivan's code:

```
# serve any request starting with `/rest` with the following location
location ~ /rest {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
    }
}

# assuming every request starting with '/wp-' and every other request for PHP file
# (except those starting with '/rest') are WordPress related
#location ~ (^/wp-|\.php$) {
location ~ /wp- {
    root /var/www/vhosts/speedskatingnews.info/ngx;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cms/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
    }
}

# serve all the other requests with the Angular app
location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I was need to make some changes to get it to work. There is now a single problem: it is not possible to call `/wp-admin`. It is required to call `/cms/wp-admin`. This itself is not a big deal, but e.g. `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/5346?_fields=title,link,content,slug/` is working. BUT why? If `/wp-admin` doesn't work, `/wp-json` should also don't work... So I'm not sure if my edited code is really applicable.

Comment: thx a lot for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't work because `duplicate location "/" in` . But I don't know where this comes fromm, 'caus I only see one `/`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: There is definitely no second `/` location in this config. You can run `nginx -T` to see the whole configuration with all the included files.

Comment: I could find the mistake and have attached my code to your code. There is still a problem :-(